# Using Databricks connect through proxy

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I would like to use databricks-connect through a proxy requiring authentication.

I am using a Linux O.S. and Azure Databricks. I have configured databricks-connect within my home network.
*Databricks-connect test* correctly works.

Instead, in my office I need to set up a proxy. This proxy uses a basic realm authentication. Usually, I would set the environment variable HTTPS_PROXY as http://username:passwd@host:port.

However, *databricks-connect test* throws me an error saying the proxy variable is matched with a regex HOST:POST. Of course the environment variable does not match. Removing username:passwd results in a 407 response from the proxy.

Does someone know how to make it work?

Thanks in advance